# java.lang.NullPointerException on save object / Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

I'm trying to save an object in my MySQL database with Hibernate and Spring, in HQL.
However, when saving, here is the error message:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

```
public void addCountry(Country country) throws Exception {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        //Add new Country object
        Country c = new Country();
        c.setId(""); //id value is auto into mySQL
        c.setCity1(country.getCity1());
        c.setCity2(country.getCity2());
        session.save(c);

        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add stack trace to question. Point the line in the source code where the exception happens. And why _c.setId(""); //id value is auto into mySQL_ if it is auto?

Comment: Try removing  c.setId("");

Comment: In addition to the stacktrace you should post also the definition of the `Country` if you need help.

Comment: are you sure parameter country is not null?

Answer (score 0):

As juanlumn said remove setId("") as Hibernate will create this for you. Need to debug to see which object is causing NullPointerException like need to know if you are getting Hibernate session which will let you know that you have  configured Hibernate properly. Again you are passing country as method parameter but saving c by populating in dao itself not sure why.